# jq key, value for each shell script

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, foreach, jq

I'm trying to use every Key,Value of an output and pipe it to another command.
Here is what I'm trying to use:

```
INSTANCE_ID=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID"
```

With the above command, I have the following output:

```
{
"Tags": [
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "A-VALUE",
        "Key": "A-KEY"
    },
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "B-VALUE",
        "Key": "B-KEY"
    },
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "C-VALUE",
        "Key": "C-KEY"
    },
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "D-VALUE",
        "Key": "D-KEY"
    },
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "E-VALUE",
        "Key": "E-KEY"
    },
    {
        "ResourceType": "instance",
        "ResourceId": "i-0342a609edf80001a",
        "Value": "F-VALUE",
        "Key": "G-KEY"
    },
    {
```

Now I want to pipe each Key,Value to the following command:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=H-KEY,Value=H-VALUE
```

Where the quantity and values of Key,Value are variable. So I believe I need a "for each".

May you help me?

It's like: For each Key,Value, do:

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=A-KEY,Value=A-VALUE
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=B-KEY,Value=B-VALUE
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=C-KEY,Value=C-VALUE
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=N...-KEY,Value=N...-VALUE
```

Comment: With that, I get the Key, Values: aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" --region $REGION | jq -r '.Tags[] | "\(.Key) \(.Value)"'

Now I need to loop, right?

Answer (score 5):

[jq](/questions/tagged/jq) has a [`@sh` directive](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) to output values properly quoted for the shell:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags --filters "Name=resource-id,Values=$INSTANCE_ID" \
| jq -r '.Tags[] | @sh "aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key=\(.Key),Value=\(.Value)"'
```

Given your input, this outputs

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='A-KEY',Value='A-VALUE'
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='B-KEY',Value='B-VALUE'
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='C-KEY',Value='C-VALUE'
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='D-KEY',Value='D-VALUE'
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='E-KEY',Value='E-VALUE'
aws ec2 create-tags --resources XXXXX --tags Key='G-KEY',Value='F-VALUE'
```

To execute those as commands pipe into `sh`:

```
aws ec2 describe-tags ... | jq -r ... | sh
```

---

jq is quite an adventure. You need to add a "select" filter to remove keys that start with "aws:"

```
jq -r '
    .Tags[] | 
    select(.Key | test("^aws:") | not) |
    @sh "aws ... --tags Key=\(.Key),Value=\(.Value)"
'
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

However, I need one last detail:

Is it possible to ignore keys that start with "Key": "aws:***"?